# Separating $3n$ points on the plane by a line

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving, combinatorial-geometry

I am trying to solve a problem in geometry (a contest-type question), and I wondering if the following result is true. (If it is true, then it makes life much easier!)

> Suppose there are $3n$ points in the plane, no three of which are collinear. Then there exists a line $L$ on the plane such that $3$ of the points lie on one side of $L$, and $3(n-1)$ of the points lie on the other side of $L$.

I am relatively confident that the assertion is true. I have drawn a lot of special cases, but general proof is out of my reach. I appreciate any hints.

Comment: I think we can prove this by starting from the left most point and moving to the right one point at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a finite number of directions parallel to a line connecting two points.  Pick a different direction, and use lsp's comment.

Comment: I think that does it! Excellent +1

Comment: It's worth noting that this proof makes no use of non-collinearity.  (It works especially well if *all* the points are on a *single* line!)

Answer (score 2):

Take any line that is part of the convex hull of the points. This line includes two points, let them be $A$ and $B$, of the $3n$, and $3n-2$ points are on one side of it.

Start rotating that line, holding $A$ constant, such that $B$ is on the other side (relative to the $3n-2$ points), until it "hits" another point. (It can never hit more than one at the same time, otherwise $A$ and these would be colinear.) Take that line, move it slightly away from $B$. Voilà, your $L$, isn't it?

[edit] Alternative to the "rotate that line" intuition, the convex hull of all points except $B$ contains two lines starting from $A$, one of which is *not* part of the convex hull of all points including $B$. This is the line you want.

To see that you can always move a line $L'$ with $a$ points on one side, $b$ points on it and $c$ points on the other side such that the moved line has $a+b$ points on one side and none on it, find the closest among the $c$ points and the line parallel to $L'$ that is half the closest distance away from $L'$ towards that point. (As @lsp points out, this idea alone can be used to show what you want.)

Comment: Interesting idea! Thank you. +1 Do you mean "Take that line, move it slightly away from [the point it "hits"]" instead of "Take that line and move it slightly away from  $B$". Because the line is already away from $B$, isn't it? Or maybe you mean "Take that line and move it slightly away from  $A$"

Comment: @Prism I meant "such that the line is farther away from $B$ than before". When $A$ is on the line, "move away from $A$" does not, technically, tell you to which side of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I think proof by induction works. You will apply the induction hypothesis to get a line $L$ that separates $3(n-1)$ and 6 points and then since no 3 of the points are colinear by parallel translation of $L$ you get the line you want.